# I wanna create two lists gridview.count, but in result i have free space in list, how do it correctly?

Tags: flutter, listview

I try to put items from one list to two screens.
I have a list of items with categories (just part of list here):

```
    class Sweets with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Sweet> _allSweets = [
    Sweet(
      categories: 'Данкины',
      id: '1',
      images: 'assets/images/donut_pink_resize.png',
      title: 'Красный вельвет',
      price: 65,
      rating: 4.8,
      isFavorite: false,
      isDonuts: true,
      isBurgers: false,
    ),
    Sweet(
      categories: 'Данкины',
      id: '2',
      images: 'assets/images/donut_chocolate.png',
      title: 'Шоколадный',
      price: 75,
      rating: 4.1,
      isFavorite: false,
      isDonuts: true,
      isBurgers: false,
    ),
Sweet(
      categories: 'Бургеры',
      id: '7',
      images: 'assets/images/chiken_burger.png',
      title: 'Сочная курочка',
      price: 125,
      rating: 4.8,
      isFavorite: false,
      isDonuts: false,
      isBurgers: true,
    ),
    Sweet(
      categories: 'Бургеры',
      id: '8',
      images: 'assets/images/meat_burger.png',
      title: 'Мясной',
      price: 65,
      rating: 4.8,
      isFavorite: false,
      isDonuts: false,
      isBurgers: true,
    ),
```

I want to create screens with several lists, first screen only with burgers:

```
child: GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio:
                (SizeConfig.itemWidth / SizeConfig.itemHeight),
            children: [
              ...List.generate(sweets.length, (index) {
                if (sweets[index].isBurgers)
                  return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                    value: sweets[index],
                    child: SweetCard(),
                  );
                return SizedBox.shrink();
              }),
            ],
          ),
```

and second screen only with donuts:

```
child: GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio:
                (SizeConfig.itemWidth / SizeConfig.itemHeight),
            children: [...List.generate(sweets.length, (index) {
                if (sweets[index].isDonuts)
                  return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                    value: sweets[index],
                    child: SweetCard(),
                  );
                return SizedBox.shrink();
              }),
            ],
          ),
```

[first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXhL0.jpg)
[second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxjV4.jpg)

but in result i have free space in screen, it looks like invisible items betweet different categories on the screen, how i can fix it?
Parent widget:

```
    class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = '/dindon_main';
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelecion);
  }

  void _handleTabSelecion() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      initialIndex: 3,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person_add),
                  title: Text(
                    'Профиль',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProfileScreen.routeName);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidHeart),
                  title: Text(
                    'Любимое',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, FavoriteScreen.routeName);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                  title: Text(
                    'Настройки',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, SettingsScreen.routeName);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                  title: Text(
                    'Корзина',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, CartScreen.routeName);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                  title: Text(
                    'Выйти',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    context.read<AuthentificationService>().signOut();
                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                        context, AuthentificationPage.routename);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                  title: Text(
                    'Выйти из Google',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // ! -  Добавить страницу logout google
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, GoogleLogoutPage.routeName);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                  },
                  tooltip:
                      MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
                );
              },
            ),
            actions: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
                  right: getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
                ),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: getProportionateScreenWidth(60),
                  height: getProportionateScreenHeight(60),
                  child: Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProfileScreen.routeName);
                        },
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage:
                              AssetImage('assets/images/avatar_circle2.png'),

                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              labelColor: Colors.black,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  text: 'Пончики',
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/donut32-min.svg',
                    color:
                        _tabController.index == 0 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Бургеры',
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/burger_32-min.svg',
                    color:
                        _tabController.index == 1 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Блинчики',
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/puncake2_32.svg',
                    color:
                        _tabController.index == 2 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Пицца',
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/pizza_32.svg',
                    color:
                        _tabController.index == 3 ? Colors.black : Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(248, 219, 221, 1.0),
          body: TabBarView(
            // controller: _pageController,
            controller: _tabController,
            children: [
              DonutsScreen(),
              BurgersScreen(),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
              PizzaScreen(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you mind posting some screenshots and the parent widgets of that grid view? Then only we can identify the issue.

Comment: @Arjunraj kokkadan done..